# Android OpenGL - What is the best way to add title screen (and later menu) before main game engine?

Tags: android, opengl-es, title

I am making an Android game based on OpenGL 2.0.
It's simply a main activity class, renderer class where everything runs in onDrawFrame and myGLSurfaceView that holds touch events. Works good as for now.

The question is - how should i proceed with making a start screen, and further start menu.
So first I want to show a title screen, and after touch it should run the game. The thing is I don't have an idea how should it be done - Im considering this options:

1. On start I can draw a flat textured rectangle in onDrawFrame with title screen, after touch it'll show the rest of the game and hide the tile screen. It's easy to do, yet I have a feeling that it's not how it should be done.
2. I thought about separate activities - each running separate renderers and separate GLSurfaceViews - on thouch one will close and another will start. But I couldn't do that - I mean I cant run from MyGLSurfaceView onTouch method a call to MyActivity class to start another activity, I can't also start another activity from MyGLSurfaceView becouse getApplicationContext doesn't work there. I tried this:

   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewGameActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
   And I still don't even know if it's the right way to do it - start new activity, new GLSurvaceView and Renderer, close old ones?
3. I also consider to draw titlescreen using start activity with 2d canvas and then after touch close it and run OpenGL activity?

or maybe there's another way it should be done? Please give me any suggestions :)

Comment: Personally this sounds like a Game Development question; have you tried looking for answers there? Not to say this isn't answerable, it just might have more luck at the other site.

Comment: What are you planning on having on the titlescreen that requires the advanced drawing functions you get through openGL or the 2d canvas? If you are only drawing play/load/setting buttons and maybe a background you can just use the regular Android view objects.

Comment: @Java The thing is that I wouldn't like it to look like standard buttons, and making it at canvas shouldn't be a big deal - problem is that I don't know if it should be run in separate activity or the same one as the rest of game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer option 1:
**- Splash screen should be done in opengl**
- A game should have 1 full-screen Activity.
- Support single-orientation (portrait or landscape), that avoid recreating activity

Why?
- That allow your game create GLSurfaceView sooner and perform some resource loading while splash screen is show. You can also add a progress bar to splash screen.
- Try to do all in opengl so we can port the game other platform easily.

Comment: I'm not sure why using standard views or a canvas would make any of those points invalid. The only thing that would be any easier is porting, like you said, but a splash screen is trivial to create in just about anything.

Comment: @damphat Thx a lot, actually that's what I wanted to hear but I wasn't sure if it's the right way :)

Comment: @Geobits OpenGL resources (texture, vbo, ...) must be loaded by special thread created by GLSurfaceView. So we must create GLSurfaceView before showing our splash screen. Yes, splash screen is trivial, but make sure it not prevent GLSurefaceView from loading resource. We can use splash as a child activity or a top view, but never load GameActivity after SplashActivity. (I mean we can loading resources synchronously while splash is showing)